# <JSP> How to display different input text boxes with select box options

Tags: jsp

I have a code as following

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <select name="selectOp" id="selectOp" style="height:19px;">
        <option value="clipNo">CLIP NO</option>
        <option value="tapeNo">TAPE NO</option>
        <option value="cdNa">CONTENT NAME</option>
    </select>
        <c:if test="${selectOp == 'clipNo'}" >
            <span class="br"><input type="text" id="searchWord" name="searchWord" style="width:500px;height:19px;" /></span>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${selectOp == 'tapeNo'}" >
            <span class="br"><input type="text" id="searchWord2" name="searchWord2" style="width:500px;height:19px;" /></span>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${selectOp == 'tapeNo'}" >
            <span class="br"><input type="text" id="searchWord3" name="searchWord3" style="width:500px;height:19px;" /></span>
        </c:if>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If I select clipNo, then searchbar should be id="searchWord" name="searchWord"

If I select tapeNo, then searchbar should be id="searchWord2" name="searchWord2"

If I select videoNo, then searchbar should be id="searchWord3" name="searchWord3"

But for some reason, the search bar don't show up. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript/jQuery function to generate dynamic textfield

#### JSP

```
<select name="selectOp" id="selectOp" style="height:19px;" onchange="dynamicTextField()">
    <option value="clipNo">CLIP NO</option>
    <option value="tapeNo">TAPE NO</option>
    <option value="cdNa">CONTENT NAME</option>
</select>
// div to add text fields dyanamically using jQuery
<div id="dyanamicDivElement"></div>
```

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```
function dynamicTextField()
{
    var selectVal = $('#selectOp').val();
    if(selectVal == "clipNo")
    {
        var newTextField = "<span class='br'><input type='text' id='searchWord' name='searchWord' style='width:500px;height:19px;' /></span>";
        $('#dyanamicDivElement').append(newTextField);
    }
    else if(selectVal == "tapeNo")
    {
        var newTextField = "<span class='br'><input type='text' id='searchWord2' name='searchWord2' style='width:500px;height:19px;' /></span>";
        $('#dyanamicDivElement').append(newTextField);
    }
    else if(selectVal == "videoNo")
    {
        var newTextField = "<span class='br'><input type='text' id='searchWord3' name='searchWord3' style='width:500px;height:19px;' /></span>";
        $('#dyanamicDivElement').append(newTextField);
    }
}
```

### Related link

- [jQuery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

---

Now answer to your question

> But for some reason, the search bar don't show up.

This is because there is no variable like `${selectOp}` in page, request, session, application scope. It is HTML element.

The web container evaluates a variable that appears in an expression by looking up its value according to the behavior of `PageContext.findAttribute(String)`.
For example, when evaluating the expression `${selectOp}`, the container will look for `selectOp` in the page, request, session, and application scopes and will return its value. If `selectOp` is not found, `null` is returned.

### Related link

- [EL variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)